# DataGridTemplateColumn binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I want to have custom column in `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Click">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

However, clicking `CheckBox` (check/uncheck) doesn't trigger property setter

```
bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        _isChecked = value; // setting breakpoint here
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The setter **sometimes** get called and I fail understand when exactly it happens: when I switch row? when I double-click another cell? Or what?

If I use `ListView` then binding is triggered **immediately**.

My question: what is going on? How to make setter called as soon as I tick/untick `CheckBox`?

Comment: <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
Should fix your problem.

Comment: @Mr.B, thanks, this was it.

Comment: You are welcome.
Please verify it as correct aswer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`

Should fix your problem.

Comment: I totally forgot about `UpdateSourceTrigger` and it wasn't easy to figure out it was `LostFocus` (as I explained in the question it was *erratic*).